# Remove Scientific Notation from R plot

Tags: r, scientific-notation

I am trying to remove scientific notation from the x-axis of the histogram. options(scipen=999) did not work.

Thank you for the help.

Seperate Lot into different blocks

```
hist(CatLotData2$'LOT SIZE')

CatLotData2$LotCat <-cut(CatLotData2$'LOT SIZE',
    c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,12500,15000,17500,Inf))

##I have tried several options to remove scientific notation from the histogram.Below is what I have tried and failed.

plot(CatLotData2$LotCat)

## What I have tried to use and failed.
options(scipen = 999)

options("scipen"=0, "digits"=5)

format(1e03, scientific=FALSE) ## creates output on separate chart 
format(3e03, scientific=FALSE)
format(4e03, scientific=FALSE)

plot(CatLotData2$LotCat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `cut`.  Use the `dig.lab` to adjust the digits

```
CatLotData2$LotCat <-cut(CatLotData2$'LOT SIZE',
c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,12500,
        15000,17500,Inf), dig.lab = 10)
```

Comment: @Pitcrew1001: if this is the answer you were looking for,  you should accept it!